# Generics in Inner Classes

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings, inner-classes, unchecked

I have a question when it comes to *generic types* in nested classes.
If I have one class (Class1) which takes the type **E** and also has an internal class (Class2) which I also want to take type **E** which should be the same as the **E** of Class1 in all cases. Class2 is a private internal class, so it will only ever be used by instances of Class1; which means it will never ever have any other **E**.

However, I get a bunch of warnings from this code;
First of all, I get "*Type safety: The expression of type Class1.Class2[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to Class1.Class2[]*" when creating the Class2 array in the Class1 constructor.
And then I also get "*The type parameter E is hiding the type E*" at the Class declaration of Class2 (*private class Class2*)

At the same time, while I can add the type when declaring the array variable outside of the constructor, I cannot do so when creating the array (I get "*Cannot create a generic array of Class1.Class2*" if I try).

I don't quite understand how I am supposed to do this if I want code that does not produce any warnings. How can I do to get rid of the two warnings I mentioned above?

```
/**
 * @author you-know-who
 * @param <E>
 */
public class Class1<E> {

    public final E main;
    public final Class2<E>[] rest;

    public Class1(E main, E[] rest) {
        this.main = main;
        this.rest = new Class2[rest.length];
        int index = 0;
        for (E e : rest) {
            this.rest[index] = new Class2<E>(e);
            index++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @author you-know-who
     * @param <E>
     */
    private class Class2<E> {
        public final E e;

        public Class2(E e) {
            this.e = e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Class2 can use E without being generic. It's technically `Class1<E>.Class2`

Comment: Generics and arrays do not mix, due to reification.  Use Lists or Collections, not arrays.

Answer (score 5):

> If I have one class (Class1) which takes the type E and also has an
>   internal class (Class2) which I also want to take type E which should
>   be the same as the E of Class1 in all cases.

So you should not declare twice the generic : in the class and its inner class.
Indeed, don't make the inner class a generic class and instead use in the inner class the `E` declared in the outer class such as :

```
public class Class1<E> {

    public final E main;
    public final Class2[] rest;

    public Class1(E main, E[] rest) {
       ...
    }

    private class Class2 {
        public final E e;

        public Class2(E e) {
            this.e = e;
        }
    }
}
```

The `E` type is indeed visible in the inner class as inner classes have access to other members of the enclosing class (including the generic of the class).

Comment: What if Class2 is an inner `interface` instead?